# SQL queries code

Tags: sql, oracle

the query. 
1. the company has decided to increase the price of ford vans by 10% while all other prices remain the same. Produce the new price list for all vehicles in the system. 
i did this code but it's still getting me the message.

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
Select price, type_of_vehicle, make_of_vehicle 
From type of vehicle, make of vehicle 
Where type_of_vehicle = 'van'
Make_of_vehicle = 'ford' 
Price = Price * 1.10;
```

could someone help with the right answer ?!

Comment: Are your table really named `type of vehicle` and `make of vehicle`? In that case you need to put them in quotes: `FROM "type of vehicle"` etc. It's generally not advisable to have table names like this and you should consider using the modern `JOIN` syntax for SELECT statements as well (what you actually want here is an UPDATE statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem in the table's names cause there is space in it.table names do not have space in them(it is not common), try to use the correct table name(maybe sth as follow). plus you have to use a `and` after a condition in where. **if you want to retrieve some information from your database**: (still not sure what is your tables' structures)

```
Select price, type_of_vehicle, make_of_vehicle 
From typeOfVehicle, makeOfVehicle 
Where type_of_vehicle = 'van'
and Make_of_vehicle = 'ford' 
and price.VehicleId = typeOfVehicle.VehicleId
and typeOfVehicle.VehicleId = makeOfVehicle.VehicleId
```

**EDIT** :
and for what you want to do, which is updating the price you should be writing sth like this :

```
update price
set price = price *1.10;
```

This statement will update all the records, in order to update only the records with a specific attribute from another table, I need to know the structure of your tables and what are their **PK** and **FK**. I could help you more if I know them.

Comment: yes, this has worked for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error here

```
From type of vehicle, make of vehicle
```

If those are the real names of your tables, then you need to enclose them into quotes:

```
From "type of vehicle", "make of vehicle"
```

If you need to update the values, as your assignment seems to suggest, then you will need to execute an [update from](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:164612348068). However, you should watch a tutorial first, as you are clearly unprepared to write Oracle code.

Answer (score 0):

You should do an update function instead.

```
UPDATE table_with_price
SET Price = (Price * 1.10)
WHERE type_of_vehicle = 'van' 
AND Make_of_vehicle = 'ford'
```

Comment: As I understand it, the question doesn't ask for the table to be updated, just for the new list of prices to be generated.  As for the syntax, it is definitely off in all databases.

Comment: i tried update and it gives me this message. ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Comment: @LukeWoodward I did it freehand at first (and that didn't work very well), but I updated it now - even though I'm still not sure about the structure. Would you give it a check?

Comment: @T.Palludan: that statement is now a valid SQL statement, on the assumption that  `table_with_price` has the three columns mentioned.  (It might not have these columns, but without further info from the questioner we won't know.)

Comment: And thus I learned something today.